# How would I pass a variable from a bitbake recipe to a makefile?

Tags: makefile, recipe, openembedded, bitbake

I'm trying to pass a variable from my bitbake (.bb) recipe to a Makefile that I have it calling.

In my recipe I have:

```
export FOO="bar"
```

When it runs the `do_compile()` method I have it calling a Makefile I generated. In the Makefile I tested the variable was set correctly via:

```
ifeq ($(FOO), "bar")
    echo $(FOO) >> ./test.txt
else
    echo "Didn't work" >> ./test.txt
endif
```

When I bake the recipe I just see "Didn't work" in the log. I thought this was very strange because if I had `FOO="bar"` in my Makefile and just ran `make`, then I would see "bar" printed in the test file. So why didn't it "pass" correctly?

I ran one more test to verify, in my Makefile I only put this line:

```
echo $(FOO) >> ./always_print.txt
```

And then after baking the recipe I see `bar` printed in my "always_print.txt" file yet I see "Didn't work" printed in test.txt...

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `make` language does not use `"` as a quoting character, so you're comparing `$(FOO)` against `"bar"` (quotes included). Just omit the quotes:

```
ifeq ($(FOO),bar)
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was making that too complex. One question for you, why was it working when I added FOO="bar" directly in my Makefile and running it with `make`? Is it because there's a difference in how it handles a local define vs. an exported one?

Comment: If you do `FOO="bar"` in the Makefile, then `$(FOO)` will include the quotes, so your original comparison will work. In `BitBake` the `"` character *is* used for quoting, so `export FOO="bar"` will result in `$(FOO)` containing the string `bar` (without quotes).

Answer (score 7):

Before defining your do_compile method, you have to define the variable EXTRA_OEMAKE which this content:

```
EXTRA_OEMAKE = "FOO=bar"
```

After that, in your do_compile method you must call 'oe_runmake'. That call invokes the command 'make', and all contents defined in EXTRA_OEMAKE variable are passed as argument to the 'make' command. Hope this helps!

Comment: The default behavior of this task is to run the oe_runmake function if a makefile (Makefile, makefile, or GNUmakefile) is found. If no such file is found, the do_compile task does nothing.